# Capture keys with TKinter with this scenario

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, keyboard-shortcuts

I would either like to capture all key strokes, or associate a key stroke to a button.  At this time, there is no user input in this game other than the user clicking buttons. I would like to assign a single keyboard letter to each button.  I was also playing with pynput, but since the program is already using TKinter, seems like I should be able to accomplish it with its features.

I can either have an on_press method in the main Game class that then calls the appropriate function for each key (same as user click the key), or perhaps there is a better way.

Most of the examples I've seen deal with the object created from tkinter class, but in this case, it's removed from my main program several levels.

This is a game I got from GitHub, and adapting to my preferences. So I'm trying to change it as little as possibly structurally.

In Graphics.py, I see this code:

```
class GraphWin(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, title="Graphics Window", width=200, height=200):
        master = tk.Toplevel(_root)
        master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, width=width, height=height)
        self.master.title(title)
        self.pack()
        master.resizable(0,0)
        self.foreground = "black"
        self.items = []
        self.mouseX = None
        self.mouseY = None
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self._onClick)  #original code
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self._mouseCallback = None
        self.trans = None

    def _onClick(self, e):
        self.mouseX = e.x
        self.mouseY = e.y
        if self._mouseCallback:
            self._mouseCallback(Point(e.x, e.y))
```

The main program is basically something like this:

```
def main():
    # first number is width, second is height
    screenWidth = 800
    screenHeight = 500
    mainWindow = GraphWin("Game", screenWidth, screenHeight)
    game = game(mainWindow)
    mainWindow.bind('h', game.on_press())  #<---- I added this 
    #listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=game.on_press, on_release=game.on_release)
    #listener.start()
    game.go()
    #listener.join()
    mainWindow.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I added a test function in the Game class, and it currently is not firing.

```
def on_press(self):
    #print("key=" + str(key))
    print( "on_press")
    #if key == keyboard.KeyCode(char='h'):
    #    self.hit()
```

Buttons are setup like this:

```
def __init__( self, win ): 
    # First set up screen
    self.win = win
    win.setBackground("dark green")
    xmin = 0.0
    xmax = 160.0
    ymax = 220.0
    win.setCoords( 0.0, 0.0, xmax, ymax )
    self.engine = MouseTrap( win )
```

then later...

```
self.play_button = Button( win, Point(bs*8.5,by), bw, bh, 'Play')
self.play_button.setRun( self.play )
self.engine.registerButton( self.play_button )
```

And finally, the Button code is in guiengine.py

```
class Button:

    """A button is a labeled rectangle in a window.
    It is activated or deactivated with the activate()
    and deactivate() methods. The clicked(p) method
    returns true if the button is active and p is inside it."""

    def __init__(self, win, center, width, height, label):
        """ Creates a rectangular button, eg:
        qb = Button(myWin, Point(30,25), 20, 10, 'Quit') """ 

        self.runDef = False
        self.setUp( win, center, width, height, label )

    def setUp(self, win, center, width, height, label):
        """ set most of the Button data - not in init to make easier
        for child class methods inheriting from Button.
        If called from child class with own run(), set self.runDef""" 

        w,h = width/2.0, height/2.0
        x,y = center.getX(), center.getY()
        self.xmax, self.xmin = x+w, x-w
        self.ymax, self.ymin = y+h, y-h
        p1 = Point(self.xmin, self.ymin)
        p2 = Point(self.xmax, self.ymax)
        self.rect = Rectangle(p1,p2)
        self.rect.setFill('lightgray')
        self.rect.draw(win)
        self.label = Text(center, label)
        self.label.draw(win)
        self.deactivate()

    def clicked(self, p):
        "Returns true if button active and p is inside"
        return self.active and \
               self.xmin <= p.getX() <= self.xmax and \
               self.ymin <= p.getY() <= self.ymax

    def getLabel(self):
        "Returns the label string of this button."
        return self.label.getText()

    def activate(self):
        "Sets this button to 'active'."
        self.label.setFill('black')
        self.rect.setWidth(2)
        self.active = True

    def deactivate(self):
        "Sets this button to 'inactive'."
        self.label.setFill('darkgrey')
        self.rect.setWidth(1)
        self.active = False

    def setRun( self, function ):
        "set a function to be the mouse click event handler"
        self.runDef = True
        self.runfunction = function

    def run( self ):
       """The default event handler.  It either runs the handler function
       set in setRun() or it raises an exception."""
       if self.runDef:
           return self.runfunction()
       else:
           #Neal change for Python3
           #raise RuntimeError, 'Button run() method not defined'
           raise RuntimeError ('Button run() method not defined')
           return False  # exit program on error
```

Extra code requested:

```
class Rectangle(_BBox):

    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        _BBox.__init__(self, p1, p2)

    def _draw(self, canvas, options):
        p1 = self.p1
        p2 = self.p2
        x1,y1 = canvas.toScreen(p1.x,p1.y)
        x2,y2 = canvas.toScreen(p2.x,p2.y)
        return canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,options)

    def clone(self):
        other = Rectangle(self.p1, self.p2)
        other.config = self.config
        return other

class Point(GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        GraphicsObject.__init__(self, ["outline", "fill"])
        self.setFill = self.setOutline
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def _draw(self, canvas, options):
        x,y = canvas.toScreen(self.x,self.y)
        return canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x+1,y+1,options)

    def _move(self, dx, dy):
        self.x = self.x + dx
        self.y = self.y + dy

    def clone(self):
        other = Point(self.x,self.y)
        other.config = self.config
        return other

    def getX(self): return self.x
    def getY(self): return self.y
```

**Update**

Some of the notes I put in the comments: 
It is using this: http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py John Zelle's graphic.py.

http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf - See class _BBox(GraphicsObject): for common methods.

I see class GraphWin has an anykey - where it captures the keys. But how would I get that back in my main program, especially as an event that would fire as soon as the user typed it?

Do I need to write my own listener - see also [python graphics win.getKey() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156910/)…. That post has a while loop waiting on the keys. I'm not sure where I would put in such a while loop, and how that would trigger into the "Game" class to fire an event. Do I need to write my own listener?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-to-activate-tkinter-buttons-with-keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518052)

Comment: It does help.  But mine is more complex  I tried "self.hit_button.bind('p', self.play)" and get compile error: "AttributeError: 'Button' object attribute 'bind'.

Comment: Next idea is to pass the hotkey in my Button parameters and try setting inside the Button Class.

Comment: Nope, that won't work.  Not sure why it has it's own Button class in the code I posted. That Button doesn't seem to have any bind.

Comment: ***`self.hit_button.bind('p', self.play)`***: `'p'` isn't valid, read up on [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: Yes, I've been looking at that all morning... It says "a The user typed an “a”. Most printable characters can be used as is. "  But I still don't have a "bind" method.  I'm wondering if this code I found, the created their own Button rather than using the TKinter button?  My Button params are totally different than the example there, and I included my Button class above.

Comment: Ah, I see "qb = Button" - that's where I need to bind... I will make a ButtonHotkey and try passing a hotkey and bind there.  Tried, but it was commented out.

Comment: His custom buttons are added in Mouse_Trap class, the registerButton method, which does self.buttons.append(_button_)

Comment: Please post the code for  `Rectangle` and `Point` classes as well?

Comment: @acw1668 - Code Added

Comment: The added code does not match with the original code, for example, there is only `_draw(self, canvas, option)` function in `Rectangle` class, but in original code, it uses `draw(win)`.  There is no `setFill()` in `Rectangle` class as well.

Comment: I'll look further into what you said, it seems to be using this: https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py  John Zelle's graphic.py

Comment: https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf - See class _BBox(GraphicsObject): for common methods.

Comment: I see class GraphWin has an anykey - where it captures the keys.  But how would I get that back in my main program, especially as an event that would fire as soon as the user typed it?

Comment: Do I need to write my own listener - see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156910/python-graphics-win-getkey-function.  That post has a while loop waiting on the keys.  I'm not sure where I would put in such a while loop, and how that would trigger into the "Game" class to fire an event.  Do I need to write my own listener?

Comment: To program your own listener, you would need to use machine code, partly because to program a listener you would need to use an existing listener. @NealWalters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the `on_press()` command not firing is due to the fact that the `.bind()` call is bound to an instance of `Canvas`. This means the canvas widget must have the focus for the keypress to register.

Use `bind_all` instead of `bind`.

Alternatives to fixing this:

1. Using `mainWindow.bind_all("h", hit)` - to bind the letter h directly to the "hit" button handler function (just make sure the hit function has the signature as follows:
   `def hit(self, event='')`
2. Using `mainWindow.bind_all("h", game.on_press)` - binds the keypress to the whole application
3. Using `root.bind("h", game.on_press)` - binds the keypress to the root window (maybe a `toplevel` is more accurate here depending on if there are multiple windows)

Related to catching any key, there are some examples over here about doing that, using the `"<Key>"` event specifier: https://tkinterexamples.com/events/keyboard

Comment: I'm playing with your first alternative.  With no parms it says "TypeError: on_press() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'key'".   I tried: "mainWindow.bind_all("h", Game.on_press(game,"h"))" and it ran, and it shows on_press fired one time with the key "h", but I think it was before the window appeared.  After the window is open, it doesn't fire.   On your alternative #2, where would that go?

Comment: First test with this looks like it will work: mainWindow.bind_all("h", game.hit) where "hit" is a function that implements the "hit" button. In other words, bind it to the button I want to run, and don't need the key_press() any more.

Comment: Working great.  Each button just has to have the dummy event added to it, like this:    " def hit(self, event=''): # Button call back".  If you want to add my 1st comment to your answer, I will award the bounty.  I think the main idea was to use bind-all instead of just bind. Thanks!

Comment: Oops I totally included the parentheses which meant was a premature call - I meant `mainWindow.bind_all("h", game.on_press)` without the parentheses to pass in the _callable_, edited to fix this. The other alternative would be using a lambda to pass the parameters in such as `mainWindow.bind_all("h", lambda event: game.on_press(game)`

Comment: Notice in the second case we don't use the parameter `event` passed in but the function will still expect it so we must add it. Glad to her you got something working with that `hit` function

Answer (score -1):

whenever you want to combine your mouse and keyboard input with widgets I strongly suggest you to use the built-in `.bind()` method. `.bind()` can have two values:

1. Type of input
2. Name of callback function

An example:

```
entry_name.bind("<Return>", function_name_here)
```

This will call the `function_name_here()` function whenever the `Return` or the `Enter` key on your keyboard is pressed. This method is available for almost all tk widgets. You can also state key combinations as well as mouse controls.(Ctrl-K, Left-click etc.). If you want to bind multiple key strokes to a certain callback function, then just bind the both with same callback function like this:

```
entry_name.bind("<Return>", function_name_here)
entry_name.bind("<MouseButton-1>", function_name_here)
```

This will allow you to call the function when either of `Return` or Left-click of the mouse are pressed.

Comment: I've already tried that, wasn't that in my question? The question is where to put it to make it work with my class structure.

Comment: Hi @NealWalters! you can state the `.bind()` method where you are declaring the widget variable and shoving it onto the screen